# How to make Psalm recognize variables from an included file

Tags: psalm-php

I have a config file that's included in a function, like this:

```php
function getConnection() {
  include 'config.php';
  return new Connection($config['host']);
}
```

The issue is to make Psalm recognize the `$config` variable from the config file. Possible? Preferable using array shape notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding a `/** @var ...` annotation above the include line:

```php
function getConnection() {
  /** @var array{host: string} $config */
  include 'config.php';
  return new Connection($config['host']);
}
```